# How to refresh Angular controllers when route redirection

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am developping a backoffice, with Angular, HTML & jQuery to have a single page application.I'm on the user authentication.
I've created a cookie to have a "user session" and I can destroy it when user log out. But I work with Bootstrap, and I have a dropdown menu with user name, and a menu on the left, and I want to hide them when user is disconnected.

I have one controller for each menu, and if I re execute them, it will hide what I want.

Example :

```
.controller('SessionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
            if (typeof $cookies.userSession === "undefined") {
                $(".nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").hide();
                $location.path("/");
            } else {
                $("#userLogin").text($cookies.userSession);
                $(".nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").show();
                $location.path("/customers");
            }
        }])
```

I've read something about $scope.digest(), and $scope.apply(), but I can't make it. Maybe with a directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something very similar with my latest app, but you don't refresh the controller. That is more jquery-style thinking. You want to use ng-show / ng-hide, and set the right vars in the controller:

```
<div ng-show="user.loggedIn"><a href="/logout" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></div>
<div ng-show="!user.loggedIn"><a href="/login">Login</a></div>
```

(You could just as easily put the pull-down menus inside the above div)

Then your controller should have

```
.controller('SessionController', function ($scope,AuthSvc) {
      $scope.user = AuthSvc.user;
      $scope.logout = function() {AuthSvc.logout();};
    });
```

When the user logs out, just set `AuthSvc.user.loggedIn` to `false`, and it will be inherited across the board. That is the beauty of the 2-way bindings.

```
.factory('AuthSvc',function() {
   return {
     user: {loggedIn:false},
     logout : function() {
        // do whatever other logout stuff you need, like deleting sessions
        this.user.loggedIn = false;
     },
     login : function() {
        // do whatever other login stuff you need, like validating with the server
        this.user.loggedIn = true;
     }
   };
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is "AuthSvc" ? How can it detect a log out action ?

Comment: `AuthSvc` is a service you create that contains the current status of the user. You call it when you want to check the user status from a controller (or other service) or change it (e.g. logout). I will edit the answer to show a bit more

Comment: Finally it works perfectly for the dropdown menu (thanks !), but for the left side nav, since it's in another controller... I tried to make it whit a condition `if (AuthSvc.user.loggedIn) {}` but it works only with a reload of the page...

Comment: That is why you have the `AuthSvc` service. Edit your q to show the left side where it isn't working.

Comment: I've solved my problem, but I must supply my AuthSvc service, and it bothers me a little...

Comment: Why does it bother you? This is good app design: separation of responsibilities, modular, all good.

Comment: It's the first time I make a SPA website, so I don't have all concepts in my head.. And I thought that this service persist datas in all controllers, but if it's normal, and a good design, I trust you ! Thanks at all !

Answer (score 1):

if you use ui-router, you can easily force a reload :

```
.controller('SessionController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies','$state', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies,$state) {
            if (typeof $cookies.userSession === "undefined") {
                $(".nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").hide();
                $state.go('home',{},{reload:'true'});
            } else {
                $("#userLogin").text($cookies.userSession);
                $(".nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").show();
                $state.go('customers',{},{reload:'true'});
            }
        }])
```

Please note that this code fragment is using states  `home` and `customers` which should be defined somwhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to achieve what you're really trying to do (which is showing/hiding stuff, not re-constructing the controller). The simplest is probably to create a `isLoggedIn` property on scope and use `ng-show`/`ng-hide` directive. Or you could then separate the login into its own template and use `ng-include` to show either the login form or the real content.

---

To address your concern about cookies and reload: You're just not thinking in Angular :) Setting cookies can be useful across multiple pages or through page reload. However, if you want to utilize Angular's ability to update displayed content automatically based on underlying data (without page reload), you need to modify the underlying data. What I mean is, you need to create a property on [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), like `isLoggedIn`, and update it too, when you're setting the cookie.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I've put a boolean with ng-show directive, but I have no reloading page, so the directive seems to be not executed, and my menu don't disapeared..

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that and you haven't provided enough code in your question for me to figure it out. The `ng-show` directive just works, so you must have something else wrong. I'll put some code into my answer to show you what I mean. ... Ah, maybe I get what you mean. I'll put it in the answer.